# Why is my JOIN not working?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables. My first table ps_product which contains id_product, price, unity and reference. I am trying to join on another table called ps_product_lang which contains a column called name.

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id_product' in field list is ambiguous
```

I have also provided my code below:

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id_product, price, unity, reference FROM ps_product JOIN ps_product_lang ON ps_product.id_product WHERE ps_product_lang.id_product = id_product"); 
    $stmt->execute();
    $product = $stmt->fetchAll();

    echo '<div class="table-responsive">';
        echo '<table class="table table-striped">';
            echo '<th>Checkbox</th><th>Product ID</th><th>Product Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Unit</th><th>Reference</th>';
                foreach ($product as $row) {
                    print '<tr>';
                        print '<td><input type="checkbox" name="'. $row["id_product"] .'" value="'. $row["id_product"] .'"></td>';
                        print '<td>'. $row["id_product"] .'</td>';
                        print '<td>'. $row["name"] .'</td>';
                        print '<td>'. $row["price"] .'</td>';
                        print '<td>'. $row["unity"] .'</td>';
                        print '<td>'. $row["reference"] .'</td>';
                    print '</tr>';
                }
        echo '</table>';
    echo '</div>';
}

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$conn = null;
```

Why is $row["name"] equal to nothing and why am I getting the error listed?

Comment: You have columns of the same name across two or more of the tables and MySQL can't work out which you're talking about. Alias each table and use preprend columns with their relevant table alias.

Comment: Specifically id_product appears to be in both tables, but isn't aliased in the select nor once on the join; but you may have other columns in your select which exist in both tables which the engine wouldn't know which to pick.

Comment: your join is also missing a crucial part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have missed the ON clause in your join query and no need of where after applied ON. And the alias of ps_product was also missing before field name id_product. Please check query below. And if another fields are also common between those two tables then alias will also needed there.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT ps_product.id_product as id_product,name, price, unity, reference FROM ps_product JOIN ps_product_lang ON ps_product_lang.id_product = ps_product.id_product");
```

Comment: This has created a table but $row["name"] is still blank?

Comment: @user6618037 You don't seem to select a name?

Comment: So how would I select the column name from ps_product_lang now I have joined the table?

Comment: "name" field was missing in your selected fields in select statement. Please check my updated query.

Comment: @user6618037 "name" is the field of ps_product_lang table or ps_product table?

Comment: @RahulPatel I just added name to the SELECT list. It works!

Comment: @user6618037 that's great. please accept my answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: @RahulPatel I will mark it as an answer in 3 minutes. Do you have any idea why it would be duplicating every row 3 times?

Comment: It depends on your records. Does there 3 records in ps_product_lang table for every product?

Comment: @RahulPatel no there is only 1.

Comment: And there is not duplicated records in ps_product table also. Right?
For a product ps_product and ps_product_lang tables have a single entry?

Comment: Can you please use "left join" in place of "join" in the query?

Comment: @RahulPatel I noticed that there are duplicates in ps_product_lang.

Comment: Yes so that's why the duplicated records are coming up.

Comment: @RahulPatel if I want to join another table called ps_product_attribute and select the reference column from that table instead of ps_product how would that be done?

Comment: Will look in to it after some time.. right now I am outside.. not on computer .

Comment: @user6618037 so you want to make join in three tables ps_product,ps_product_attribute and ps_product_lang. And want to fech reference field from ps_product_attribute table. And relation between ps_product and ps_product_attribute is also id_product. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing a join between two table, and the object of this join is two column caring the same name, SQL does not know which one column it should return to you. You could use aliases on table to help SQL engine to know which one he should take in acount :

```
SELECT  PRD.id_product, 
        price, 
        unity, 
        reference 
FROM    ps_product PRD
JOIN    ps_product_lang PRL ON PRD.id_product = PRL.id_product
```

Now SQL know that you will select the column `id_product` of the table `ps_product` and not the other column (ambigous) that got the same name.